# rolling 30 days in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':  ['27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '48002', '48002', '48002'],
        'Invoice_Date': ['2020-06-26', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-25', 
                         '2020-07-30', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-13', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-28'],
        'Difference_Date': [0,3,1,14,11,5,3,0,38,8],
        })
df
```

I need to add another column that is the average of rolling 30 days period. I tried using `rolling` but it gives me error `window must be an integer`. Since this is customer-based data, it need to be groupby `ID` as well.

My expected output is:

```
    ID      Invoice_Date    Difference_Date   Average
0   27459   2020-06-26      0                 0.00
1   27459   2020-06-29      3                 1.50
2   27459   2020-06-30      1                 1.33
3   27459   2020-07-14      14                4.50
4   27459   2020-07-25      11                5.80
5   27459   2020-07-30      5                 10.00
6   27459   2020-08-02      3                 8.25
7   48002   2020-05-13      0                 0.00
8   48002   2020-06-20      38                38.00
9   48002   2020-06-28      8                 23.00
```

Is there any efficient workaround for calculating average of rolling 30 days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving Average Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060842/moving-average-pandas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling Average in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321463/rolling-average-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because pandas needs a [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) to do `df.rolling('30D')`:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':  ['27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '27459', '48002', '48002', '48002'],
        'Invoice_Date': ['2020-06-26', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-25', 
                         '2020-07-30', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-13', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-28'],
        'Difference_Date': [0,3,1,14,11,5,3,0,38,8],
        })
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Invoice_Date'])
df = df.sort_index()
df.rolling('30D')
```

Comment: what if I need it to be sorted based on ID as well?

Comment: Calculate whatever you need using the rolling index and then sort by ID? Could you clarify why you need it to be sorted by ID?

Comment: because the data is customer based data. so the rolling 30 days should be calculated based on each customer

Comment: This sounds like a groupby: try `df.groupby('ID').rolling('30D')`